# Dropbox Ruby API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, client, dropbox

I want to use Dropbox Ruby API, I installed the gem and when I want to create a dropbox session I got this message:

uninitialized constant DropboxController::Dropbox

Is there anything to do if I want to use this api except install the gem?

The code is:

```
def authorize
  if params[:oauth_token] then
    dropbox_session = Dropbox::Session.deserialize(session[:dropbox_session])
    dropbox_session.authorize(params)
    session[:dropbox_session] = dropbox_session.serialize # re-serialize the authenticated session
    redirect_to :action => 'upload'
  else
    dropbox_session = Dropbox::Session.new('your_consumer_key', 'your_consumer_secret')
    session[:dropbox_session] = dropbox_session.serialize
    redirect_to dropbox_session.authorize_url(:oauth_callback => url_for(:action => 'authorize'))
  end
end
```

Comment: An error message without code makes it hard for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rails controller not for ruby.
For ruby you may refer to this [tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/setup#ruby) and here is the [DOCs](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-ruby-sdk-1.3-docs/index.html) for Ruby

Answer (score 0):

Require the dropbox file in your current file.

Comment: I copied the dropbox.rb to lib but the tester said it doesnt find

Comment: `code`def authorize
     if params[:oauth_token] then
       dropbox_session = Dropbox::Session.deserialize(session[:dropbox_session])
       dropbox_session.authorize(params)
       session[:dropbox_session] = dropbox_session.serialize # re-serialize the authenticated session

       redirect_to :action => 'upload'
     else
       dropbox_session = Dropbox::Session.new('your_consumer_key', 'your_consumer_secret')
       session[:dropbox_session] = dropbox_session.serialize
       redirect_to dropbox_session.authorize_url(:oauth_callback => url_for(:action => 'authorize'))
 end end
end`code`

Comment: @branni: I believe they are trying to say that you need to have this line in a file, perhaps at config/initializers/dropbox.rb: `require "dropbox"` (or whatever it's called).